# Inline code backtics not working

Tags: markdown, ghost

I've started a blog hosted on Digital Ocean, using Nginx as the web server. The `inline code` looks fine in Ghosts' preview but I've published to the web and the inline code just looks like plain text. I've reviewed the code and can't see anything wrong. Any ideas? Thank you. Edidted: Adding URL To the post so you can see the post sans inline code working: https://linuxhowto.tech/managing-users-and-groups/

````
## Adding new users

While you can use `vipw` to edit the user configuration files, it is better to run `useradd`. 

`vim /etc/default/useradd`

The output should look similar to this:  

```  
GROUP=100  
HOME=/home    
INACTIVE=-1  
EXPIRE=    
SHELL=/bin/bash  
SKEL=/etc/skel  
CREATE_MAIL_SPOOL=yes  
```  

### Useradd examples

* `useradd -c "Comment here" sarah -s /bin/bash` sets a comment         (-c) and defines the default shell (-s)   
* `useradd bob -s /usr/sbin/nologin` sets `nologin` as the users's default shell because many users don't need shell access  
* `useradd -m -u 1201 -G ops,dev linda` adds user, adds home directory (-m), adds user to groups _ops_ and _dev_ (-G), assigns _UID 1201+ (-u)  
* `useradd` creates a locked account until you run `passwd user`  

### The login configuration file

The `/etc/login.defs` file sets the configuration for the for the _Shadow Password Suite._ The following are some of its most significant attributes:

 > * `MOTD_FILE`: Defines the file that is used as _message of the day_ file. In this file, you can include messages to be displayed after the user has successfully logged into the server.

 > * `ENV_PATH`: Defines the `$PATH` variable, a list of directories that should be searched for executable files after logging in.

 > *  `PASS_MAX_DAYS`, `PASS_MIN_DAYS`, and `PASS_WARN_AGE`: Define the default password expiration properties when creating new users.

 > *  `UID_MIN`: The first UID to use when creating new users.

 > *  `CREATE_HOME`: Indicates whether or not to create a home directory for new users.

 > * `USERGROUPS_ENAB`: Set to yes to create a private group for all new users. That means that a new user has a group with the same name as the user as its default group. If set to no, all users are made a member of the group users. [^n]

### System-wide Bash shell startup files

* `/etc/profile` runs system-wide environment variables and startup         scripts  
* `/etc/bashrc` contains system-wide aliases and functions [^n]  

### Bash shell personal startup files

While creating a user, `useradd` copies the `/etc/skel` user environment configuration files to the new user's home directory. The following are the default configuration files:

* `~/.bash_profile` contains personal environment variables and startup scripts  
* `~/.bashrc` contains personal aliases and functions  
* `~/.bash_logout` contains personal scripts to run on logout[^n]  

## Using usermod to modify users

These are a couple common use cases for `usermod`:  

* `usermod -g sales mike` adds _mike_ to sales as _primary_ group  
* `usermod -aG ops lisa` adds _lisa_ to ops as a *secondary* group  

## Managing password properties

Here are some example use cases for `passwd` and `chage`:  

* `chage -E 2018-12-31 bob` sets Bob's account to expire on a specific date  
* `chage -l linda` lists account aging information  
* `passwd -n 30 -x 90 lori -w 3` sets _minimum password age_ of 30 days, a _maximum password age_ of 90 days (-w), and starts _warning_ the user 3-days before the password expires (-w)  

## Linux group management

The `useradd` command creates a default _primary group_ with the same name as the user.  

When a user creates a file, the group owner will be set to that user's primary group. Users have access to files owned by their secondary groups. 

Use the `id` command to list a user's group memberships:  

`id linda`

The output should look something like this:  
`uid=1002(linda) gid=1003(account) groups=1003(account),1001(sales)`  

A common use case for secondary groups is to share documents between departments with a file server.  

## Creating groups

To create a new group, you can use the `vigr` command to directly modify the `/etc/group` file or you can run the `groupadd` command.

* `groupadd devs` adds a group called _dev_  
* `groupadd -g 404 devproject` adds a group called _devproject_ with _Group ID (GUID) 404_  
* `grep devproject /etc/group` to confirm that you successfully added a group  

### Modifying group membership

* `usermod -g 1003 frank` changes frank's **primary** group to      account, assigning GUID of 1003  
* `usermod -aG dev lori` adds account as a _secondary_                          group for lori  
* `usermod -g sales anouk` changes anouk's _primary_ group to sales  

---------------------------------------  
[^n]: Excerpt from Sander van Vugt's [Red Hat® RHCSA™/RHCE® 7 Cert Guide Premium Edition](http://www.sandervanvugt.com/book-red-hat-rhcsa-rhce-7-cert-guide/)  
[^n]: Derived from  [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/profile.html)  
[^n]: Derived from  [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/5.1/postlfs/profile.html)
````

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be using a [CSS normalization file](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) which is resetting the standard styling of inline `code` tags. Therefore, you may need to add some additional CSS to define how you want the `code` tags to look.

How did I come to this conclusion?

First I checked the HTML source of your output and confirmed that the backticks were indeed being rendered as `code` tags. Then I used my browsers developer tools to inspect one of those `code` elements (on Chrome I right-clicked on the element and selected "inspect" from the context menu) and this is what I observed:

[image]

Notice on the left that the `code` element is selected in the bottom section and the corresponding text on the page is highlighted on the top half of the window. However, more importantly is the right column on the bottom. Note that the  blue arrow (which I added) points at the CSS rule defined by the "user agent stylesheet"; that is, the rule defined by the browser as the default when no other rules are set. As you can see, that rule is overridden (is displays as being crossed out). That means that another rule has been given precedence. As you can see, the red arrow (which I added) points to the rule which has overriden the default and that rule is defined in a stylesheet named `normalize.css`. Scrolling down that column, we also find some inherited rules from parents, etc, but those don't look as relevant. I then clicked on the `normalize.css` filename and the browser opened that file. I scrolled to the top and found the link to the [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) website.

Comment: Thank you for the detective work as it had me baffled for a solid 24 hours. I'm not sure why it didn't occur to me that the Ghost reviewer would be using the same CSS as a Ghost theme!

Comment: I was trying to do some other customization and my own CSS was overriding other elements that I didn't want it to override this go around. I think I need to learn about how the cascade works with more precision.

Comment: By the way, is it critical to have the normalize.css? I'll look it up of course or maybe just temporarily disable it to see what happens. I would imagine what happens is different on diff browsers so it might be an interesting test just for the fun of it.

Answer (score 0):

For now, I just switched themes for a quick solution and it worked. These are my notes for an RHCSA course so just getting them online fast is my goal at the moment as some other students in the course expressed interest so I'll post my notes as a series of posts. At some point, I'll customize the CSS in the original theme I was using.